# codeigniter get data by selection of dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

> How to get data by selecting the drop-down in CodeIgniter.

Below is my code it does not work. The below code is not working properly when I selecting an option in the drop down and when I submit page appearing empty. when click please help me to get data. I am doing it in CodeIgniter. I want to get data from the database . I think the code is perfect am new to CodeIgniter the below code is not working properly the page appearing empty when click please help me to get data. I am doing it in CodeIgniter. I want to get data from the database . I think the code is perfect am new to CodeIgniter.

**view:**

```
<?php echo form_open('super_admin/believers_controller/view_believerr/' , array('class' => 'form-horizontal validatable', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data') ); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> District Id</label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select name="report_type" >
            <option >Select  Id</option>
            <option value="believers">Believers</option>
            <option value="staff">staff</option>
            <option value="staff">committe members</option>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix form-actions">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-info" >
```

**controller:**

```
<?php
function view_believerr()
{
    $report_type = $this->input->get('report_type');
    if($report_type=='believers'){
        $this->load->model('believers/believers_model');
        $page_data['h']=$this->believers_model->view_believer();
        $page_data['page_name']  = 'believers/view_believer';
        $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
    }
}
?>
```

**model:**

```
<?php
function view_believer()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_believers');
    return $query;
}
?>
```

I want to get data from database . I think the code is perfect am new to codeigniter the below code is not working properly the  page appearing empty when click please help me to get data. I am doing it in codeigniter. I want to get data from database . I think the code is perfect am new to codeignite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use   `$this->input->post('report_type');`

Comment: hi thanks it is working..but how can i get data in same page